# adjustbox and lstnewenvironment

Tags: errors, listings, adjustbox

I'm trying to use `adjustbox` to make a frame around listings (I know that `listings` itself can do this, but its implementation produces sub-optimal results when the line heights are not equal throughout the code). Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% sanity checking: the following line works
%\lstnewenvironment{listing}{}{}

% the following line is what I'd like to do
\lstnewenvironment{listing}{\begin{adjustbox}{left,trim=0 0 0 2pt,fbox}}{\end{adjustbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
this is 
some
test
code
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

I tried defining a new listings environment that uses `adjustbox` to put a frame around the listing. However, this does not compile, but just hangs on running `pdflatex`:

```
*         % I just pressed enter here
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*\end     % typing \end does not work either ;)

*\end

*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
```

In Texmaker, `pdflatex` is a bit more chatty: "Emergency stop. <> test.tex (job aborted, no legal \end found)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the macro version `\adjustbox{<options}{<box contents>}` which as the manual states also works with `\bgroup` and `\egroup`: `\adjustbox{<options}\bgroup<box contents>\egroup`. That allows the following definition:

```
\lstnewenvironment{listing}
  {\adjustbox{left,trim=0 0 0 2pt,fbox}\bgroup}
  {\egroup}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% the following line is what I'd like to do
\lstnewenvironment{listing}
  {\adjustbox{left,trim=0 0 0 2pt,fbox}\bgroup}
  {\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
this is 
some
test
code
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```