# Defining a centered shadowboxed listings environment

Tags: listings, environments, boxes, adjustbox, fancybox

I'm trying to define a environment for code listings wrapped in a shadowbox and centered in the line.  Using this code, I can generate the kind of output that I want:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{center}
  \shadowbox{%
    \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=6]
      line of code
      line of code
    \end{lstlisting}%
  }
\end{center}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

This produces output like this:

[image: code listing in a shadowbox in a center environment]

My problem arises when trying to abstract this into an environment.  I've seen the some related questions:

- [How to center a listing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-to-center-a-listing) The answer in this question suggests using `tabular` environment to center the listing, which works, but in the present case, the `shadowbox` serves the same purpose (being just big enough to hold the listing).
- [How to center a lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85489/how-to-center-a-lstlisting) In this question the `tabular` technique doesn't work, but the answer shows how to save the contents of the listing in an `Sbox` (from `fancybox`) and set it in a `parbox` in a `centerline`.
- [adjustbox and lstnewenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116685/adjustbox-and-lstnewenvironment) This question actually involves creating frames around listings, and seems to be the most relevant to my question. The answer depends on `adjustbox`, which supports a simple frame, but not the shadowbox from fancybox.
- [Why does pdfLaTeX fail when I try to use `begin{lstlisting}` inside a user-defined environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27640/why-does-pdflatex-fail-when-i-try-to-use-beginlstlisting-inside-a-user-defin/27641#27641) The answer here points out that it's tough to define environments in which `verbatim`-like environments will appear, and so it's best to use `lstnewenvironment`.

Based on these approaches, I've gotten as far as unsuccessfully trying to use `lstnewenvironment`.  Just trying to get a centered listing, as below, fails (error message follows):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\lstnewenvironment{CenteredShadowboxListing}[1][]{%
  \begin{center}%
    \lstset{#1}%
  }{%
  \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{CenteredShadowboxListing}[gobble=2]
  line of code
  line of code
\end{CenteredShadowboxListing}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

This fails with the error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \lst@BOLGobble@.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> mwe.tex
```

How can I define an environment that includes a code listing, puts a shadowbox around it, and centers the box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proposal using `tcolorbox`. Colors, shadows, etc. can be adjusted to your liking. You may replace `style=tcblatex` by any listings setting you want to have as default for your environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    

\newenvironment{CenteredShadowboxListing}[1][]{%
  \tcbset{listing options={style=tcblatex,#1}}\tcbwritetemp}%
  {\endtcbwritetemp%
  \tcbox[enhanced,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
  boxrule=0.6pt,drop fuzzy shadow,before=\begin{center},after=\end{center}]%
  {\tcbusetemplisting}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{CenteredShadowboxListing}
line of code
line of code
\end{CenteredShadowboxListing}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** With `tcolorbox` version `2.41` of `2013/07/23`, the code to typset the example above can be written more compact with the same result:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}% version 2.41 or newer

\newtcblisting{CenteredShadowboxListing}[1][]{%
  listing options={style=tcblatex,#1},hbox,listing only,
  enhanced,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
  boxrule=0.6pt,drop fuzzy shadow,before=\begin{center},after=\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{CenteredShadowboxListing}
line of code
line of code
\end{CenteredShadowboxListing}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very nice.  I haven't used `tcolorbox` before, so it's a nice addition to the toolbox.  It seems similar to `fancybox`'s `Sbox`/`TheSbox`, and to `adjustbox` that works with a `bgroup`/`egroup` pair.  The answer stands on its own and doesn't really need to be updated, but do you have any reference for why `tcolorbox`'s box can hold a listing while the other package's boxes fail?

Comment: Actually, while I like the look of the result, I'm having both some trouble understanding it, and getting it to work.  What version of `tcolorbox` are you using?  I'm using the version from TeXLive 2012, and `most` is an unknown option for `tcolorbox`.  If I remove the `most` option, then I get the error that `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \tcbusetemplisting`.  Finally, I don't see where in the code you provided that the listings package is getting used.   Is the code you posted a complete working example?

Comment: The [tcolorbox manual](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) explains that `\tcbusetemplisting` sets the content written to the temporary file `tcbwritetemp` as a listing.  To use this, the example also needs `\tcbuselibrary{listings}`.  The manual also shows that `most` is a library shorthand for loading all the libraries except documentation.  Even so, when I remove the `most` package option and instead to `\tcbuselibrary{most}`, I get the error "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/library/most' and I am going to ignore it."

Comment: Of course, reading through the manual and poking in the source, I see that you're the author, so _you_ probably know all this,  some of these comments are for anyone else who comes along and finds this answer.  Is the trick just that I need a later version of `tcolorbox`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Sun is rising up in Europe and I see that you were busy while I was asleep ;-) First of all, the given proposal is a complete working example. But you need a recent version of `tcolorbox`; at least v2.31. The current one is v2.40 which I recommend, see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55493#55493). Updating will remove all problems.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor On the technical side, my solution writes the content of the box into a temporary file. This file is loaded again using internally `\lstinputlisting`. You could use this trick also in combination with the other boxing packages. Nevertheless, `tcolorbox` has a special support for using `listings` which makes the code compact.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've edited the code because the passing of the environment option was without effect in the old code. You may replace `style=tcblatex` by any `listings` setting you want to have as default for your environment. Note that `gobble` will not work because of using `\lstinputlisting` (restriction coming from `listings`).

Comment: After updating TeXLive to the 2013 version, this works like a charm.  My colleagues will probably be unhappy with me if they have to run the very long install, but that would be another question I suppose ([What do I do about colleagues who hate downloading big TeXLive installations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/xxxx/what-do-I-do-...)).  Thanks for the very nice looking answer!

Answer (score 2):

> [adjustbox and lstnewenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116685/adjustbox-and-lstnewenvironment) This question actually involves
>   creating frames around listings, and seems to be the most relevant to
>   my question. The answer depends on `adjustbox`, which supports a
>   simple frame, but not the `\shadowbox` from `fancybox`.

Well, `adjustbox` does not provide a shadow box by itself but allows the usage of other box commands using the `precode` key:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\lstnewenvironment{CenteredShadowboxListing}[1][]{%
  \noindent\adjustbox{precode=\shadowbox,center,vspace=\bigskipamount}\bgroup
    \lstset{#1}%
  }{%
  \egroup%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{CenteredShadowboxListing}[gobble=2]
  line of code
  line of code
\end{CenteredShadowboxListing}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Here the command form of `\adjustbox` is used instead of the environment form, which is fine as `\adjustbox` is special command which accepts `\bgroup` .. `\egroup` instead of `{` .. `}`. Using the environment form can cause issues in this nested definition.

Comment: if the ```CenteredShadowboxListing``` is inside an itemize environment, does it center properly ?