# Customise bullet points inside shadowbox

Tags: tcolorbox, shadows, fancybox

I'm writing a report and using shadowbox for some important points. I have used the code below and it is working fine. However, when I tried to use the bullet points an extra space is added to the start of the shadowbox. I not sure what is the problem?. I found another way to do the shadowbox by using [xcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124601/defining-a-centered-shadowboxed-listings-environment), but I couldn't figure out how to change the parameters to get same as the below shadowbox.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}  
\usepackage{fancybox}

\newcommand\Cshadowbox{\VerbBox\@Cshadowbox}
 \def\@Cshadowbox#1{%
\setbox\@fancybox\hbox{\fbox{#1}}%
 \leavevmode\vbox{%
  \offinterlineskip
 \dimen@=\shadowsize
 \advance\dimen@ .5\fboxrule
 \hbox{\copy\@fancybox\kern.5\fboxrule\lower\shadowsize\hbox{%
  \color{ShadowColor}\vrule \@height\ht\@fancybox \@depth\dp\@fancybox   \@width\dimen@}}%
  \vskip\dimexpr-\dimen@+0.5\fboxrule\relax
  \moveright\shadowsize\vbox{%
  \color{ShadowColor}\hrule \@width\wd\@fancybox \@height\dimen@}}}

\begin{document}
 \shadowbox{
  \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\textbf{\begin{center} \textit{\begin{itemize}
          \item First item of the list  .
           \item Second item of the list.\\
           \end{itemize}}
              \bigskip 
           \end{center}
           } 
            \bigskip
            \end{varwidth}
 }
\bigskip 
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion to solve the space with current code or new suggestion ?

[image]

Comment: Remove the `\begin{center}`, and `\end{center}`, and add a `%` following `\shadowbox {` as in ` \shadowbox{%`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. What's the point of the `%` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

[image]

### Notes:

- Typically you should use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment (see *References* below). But, in this case, there is no point in centering as you care using `varwidth`.
- Since you want the entire environment in italics and bold, I would use the switches `\bfseries` and `\itshape` for the font switching instead of the macros.
- Be careful of spurious spaces. For instance, see what happens when you use `\shadowbox{%` instead of `\shadowbox{`.  Extra space that was not intended gets inserted. Now, in this particular case you may not care, but it can lead to disastrous results (see *Reference* 4).

### References:

1. [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)
2. [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)
3. [Is there a difference between \textit and \itshape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/is-there-a-difference-between-textit-and-itshape)
4. [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}  
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}
\shadowbox{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\bfseries\itshape%
      \begin{itemize}
            \item First item of the list.
            \item Second item of the list.
       \end{itemize}
   \end{varwidth}%
}%
\bigskip\par 
\shadowbox{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\bfseries\itshape%
      \begin{itemize}
            \item[]
            \item First item of the list.
            \item Second item of the list.
            \item[]
       \end{itemize}
   \end{varwidth}%
 }%
\end{document}
```