# Centering lstlisting using tcolorbox Inside Enumerate Environment

Tags: listings, enumerate, tcolorbox

I am trying to center a `lstlisting` environment using `tcolorbox` (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124607/167081)). The method does work normally but doesn't render as expected in `enumerate` environment as shown below:

[image: Output]

I have tried the following and tweaked it many times but nothing worked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{code}[1][]{%
    \tcbwritetemp}%
    {\endtcbwritetemp%
    \tcbox[before=\begin{center},after=\end{center}]%
    {\tcbusetemplisting}%
    }%

\begin{document}    
    Start a list:
    \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{--}]
        \item Inside enumerate not working.
\begin{code}
if(x == 0){
    return 0;
}else{
    return 1;
}\end{code}
    \end{enumerate}
    This is what I want to achieve inside enumerate environment
\begin{code}
if(x == 0){
    return 0;
}else{
    return 1;
}
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve the desired output while *roughly* keeping the same outline of the logic used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lstlisting`, called in `\tcbox`, uses the current total left margin (`\@totalleftmargin`) to indent the listing accordingly when it is used inside a list environment. This works well when you use `lstlisting` in list environments directly, but fails with `\tcbox`. This seems to happen because `\tcbox` already indents the box and `lstlisting` indents the code again. To me this looks like a bug in the `tcolorbox` package.

A simple fix is to reset `\@totalleftmargin` to `0pt` locally in the `code` environment:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{code}[1][]{%
    \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
    \tcbwritetemp}%
    {\endtcbwritetemp%
    \tcbox[before=\begin{center},after=\end{center}]%
    {\tcbusetemplisting}%
    }%
\makeatother
```

which gives the desired output

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanation and the answer! Works perfectly!