# TColorBox Environment with Optional Title

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to make an environment that allows the display of code snippet with title as optional parameter. The MWE provided fixes the issue if two different environments were created. I would like to combine them into one.

The approach used here might not be as straightforward because it also fixes the issue encountered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492943/centering-lstlisting-using-tcolorbox-inside-enumerate-environment). I am also open to any other approaches that might be more suitable/less complicated. Thank you in advance!

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{code}[2][]{%
    \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
    \newcommand{\foot}{#2} 
    \tcbwritetemp}%
    {\endtcbwritetemp%
    \tcbox[title = {\foot}, % The title option is present here
           before = \begin{center}, after = \end{center},
           fonttitle = \color{white}\itshape\ttfamily, colframe = blue, 
           listing only, listing options = {language = c++}
           ]%
    {\tcbusetemplisting}%
    }%
\makeatother

% This is included just to show how the final should look like
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{HowBoxSohuldLookLikeWithoutTitle}[2][]{%
    \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
    \newcommand{\foot}{#2}
    \tcbwritetemp}%
    {\endtcbwritetemp%
    \tcbox[ % The title option is removed and hence, no title bar is shown
           before = \begin{center}, after = \end{center},
           fonttitle = \color{white}\itshape\ttfamily, colframe = blue, 
           listing only, listing options = {language = c++}
           ]%
    {\tcbusetemplisting}%
    }%
\makeatother
\begin{document}    
    Start a list:
  \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{--}]
        \item Code with title:
        \begin{code}{The Title of Code}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
        \end{code}      
        \item Code without title:
        \begin{code}
if(x == 0){
    return 0;
}else{
    return 1;
}
        \end{code}
        \item My goal is to have code without title to look like the following:
        \begin{HowBoxSohuldLookLikeWithoutTitle}
if(x == 0){
    return 0;
}else{
    return 1;
}
        \end{HowBoxSohuldLookLikeWithoutTitle}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently not using the optional argument as such, instead you'd have to only use 1 argument for your environment and have that one default to being empty. Then in the second part of your environment you test whether `\foot` is empty, if so don't use the `title` key, else use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{code}[1][]{%
    \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
    \def\foot{#1} 
    \tcbwritetemp}%
    {\endtcbwritetemp%
      \ifx\foot\@empty
        \tcbox[before = \begin{center}, after = \end{center},
               fonttitle = \color{white}\itshape\ttfamily, colframe = blue, 
               listing only, listing options = {language = c++}
               ]%
        {\tcbusetemplisting}%
      \else
        \tcbox[title = {\foot}, % The title option is present here
               before = \begin{center}, after = \end{center},
               fonttitle = \color{white}\itshape\ttfamily, colframe = blue, 
               listing only, listing options = {language = c++}
               ]%
        {\tcbusetemplisting}%
      \fi
    }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
    Start a list:
  \begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{--}]
        \item Code with title:
        \begin{code}[The Title of Code]
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
        \end{code}      
        \item Code without title:
        \begin{code}
if(x == 0){
    return 0;
}else{
    return 1;
}
        \end{code}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]